# call broadcast receiver studys

Tags: java, android, kotlin

class CallReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {

```
// BroadcastReceiver class that captures phone call events

@SuppressLint("ServiceCast")
override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
    try {
        // Get an instance of MyPreferences to store and retrieve user preferences
        val preferences = MyPreferences.getInstance(context)

        // Check if the event should be handled based on user preferences
        if (!shouldHandleEvent(preferences)) {
            return
        }

        // Get the AudioManager to access the device's audio settings
        val audioManager = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager?
        val ringerMode = audioManager?.ringerMode ?: AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL

        // Check if the event should be handled based on the current ringer mode
        if (!shouldHandleRingerMode(preferences, ringerMode)) {
            return
        }

        // Get the PowerManager to manage the device's power state
        val powerManager = context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager?
        // Check if the screen is on
        val isScreenOn = powerManager?.isInteractive == true

        // If the screen is on and the user prefers not to flash, do not process
        if (isScreenOn && preferences.prefNotFlashWhenScreenOn) {
            return
        }

        // Handle the phone call state based on the received intent
        handlePhoneCallState(context, intent, preferences)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // Handle any unexpected exceptions and print the stack trace
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}

// Check whether the event should be handled based on user preferences
private fun shouldHandleEvent(preferences: MyPreferences): Boolean {
    return preferences.prefFlashInSilentMode &&
            preferences.prefFlashInVibrateMode &&
            preferences.prefFlashInSoundMode
}

// Check whether to handle the event based on the current ringer mode
private fun shouldHandleRingerMode(preferences: MyPreferences, ringerMode: Int): Boolean {
    return when (ringerMode) {
        AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT -> preferences.prefFlashInSilentMode
        AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE -> preferences.prefFlashInVibrateMode
        AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL -> preferences.prefFlashInSoundMode
        else -> false
    }
}

// Handle the phone call state based on the received intent
private fun handlePhoneCallState(context: Context, intent: Intent, preferences: MyPreferences) {
    try {
        // Get an instance of FlashLightUtil to control flash operations
        val flashUtil = FlashLightUtil.getInstance(context)

        // Process the phone call state based on the received intent
        when (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)) {
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING -> {
                // Turn on the flash when a call is ringing
                Log.e("call", "Incoming call - Flash turned on")
                flashUtil.turnOnFlash()
            }
            TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK, TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE -> {
                // Turn off the flash and remove the callback when the call ends or goes to idle
                Log.e("call", "Call ended - Flash turned off and callback removed")
                flashUtil.turnOffFlashAndRemoveCallBack()
            }
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // Handle any unexpected exceptions and print the stack trace
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

}

**In this broadcast class, it is supposed to catch the calls coming to the user and turn the flash on and off, but there is no status when the call comes, it is also defined in the receiver manifest file. when I want to print logcate, I still can't get a result. thank you in advance for your help.**

**I don't get any error message in Logcat, when I compile my project, it runs smoothly.**

**I use android studio**

***I indicated in the comment lines what kind of logic is in my code***